# Limiting number of rows in contentResolvser.query to get any group of rows

Tags: android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

How can I pick any group of rows if I know the first and last ID?
Suppose the table has IDs from 1 to 10 and I want `contentResolver.query` to return the rows 4 to 8, how can I do that? 
I searched for that question, but all I found are solutions to return the first `n` consecutive rows:

[Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898043/how-to-add-limit-clause-using-content-provider) [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390577/limiting-number-of-rows-in-a-contentresolver-query-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses 
  **solution**
`SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 5 OFFSET 3;` [reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_limit_clause.htm)